# CMake changing a library include directory based off of calling project

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is my current project structure:

```
ProjectX
|_ projs
    |_ A ( builds an external project POO version 1 )
         add_executable(A ${A_HDRS} ${A_SRCS} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libbar>)
    |_ B ( builds an external project POO version 2 )
         add_executable(B ${B_HDRS} ${B_SRCS} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libbar>)
|
|_ libs
    |_ libbar (objects only - no linking)
              (needs POO either v1 or v2 depending on calling project)
    issue lives here -->INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${POO_BUILD_DIR}/include)
              add_library(bar OBJECT ${LIB_BAR_HDRS} ${LIB_BAR_SRCS})
```

GOAL:

I would like to be able to build from the top level including all projects and have libbar to be built with the correct dependencies. I would like to be able to have a continuous build process.

DETAILS:

When project A build builds, it needs to compile libbar with POO version1 and when project B builds it needs to compile libbar wtih POO version2. In either case it is still a version of POO. I would like to be able to pass the path to libbar from A or B.

ISSUE:

The POO_BUILD_DIR path is different depending on the project building libbar. When I build from the top level, make tries to build libbar first and doesn't find the correct includes.

QUESTION:

Does anyone know how to achieve this in cmake *or* how can I achieve finer grained control over the build order?

**UPDATE and SOLUTION:**
The problem that I was having could have been solved with Chris's solution below. However, my problem (that I should have realized earlier) is that even though it lives in a library directory and is called a library it's not a library. The naming and directory structure I can't change b/c I don't own the code base. However, I can change how I build it! My quote-unquote *solution* was to just include the files to the compilation like this: `add_executable(A ... ${libbar_hdrs} ${libbar_srcs}`

*Moral of the Story*
If someone tells you it's a library and names it a library - it still may not be. Or expressed in a colloquialism "Don't always believe what you're told".

Comment: CMake supports conditional variable setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650825/converting-old-makefile-to-cmake/16652405#16652405

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Is your suggestion that I would need a branch for every calling project? I'm thinking that this is going to continue to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's lots of ways that you could do that, but one way that I have done it in a cmake C++ project is, for each library (each folder inside of /lib in my project root) I have a secondary Cmake script which builds that library, and I use `add_subdirectory` within my primary cmake script to invoke those secondary cmake scripts.

Here's an (open source) example from my project: https://github.com/cbeck88/cegui-emscripten

For instance, if you look here you'll see how I do "in tree" (what you are talking about) libs using add_subdirectory, vs. "out of tree" (user provided) libs which I find using find_package. https://github.com/cbeck88/cegui-emscripten/blob/17f0d097f989862035e977a6b9e0b1bbb1fcdf21/CMakeLists.txt#L58

```
if (FREETYPE_IN_TREE)
  add_subdirectory(lib/freetype-2.5.5 freetype-2.5.5)
else()
  LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/freetype-2.5.5-old )
  find_package(freetype NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
  MESSAGE ( STATUS "FREETYPE found = " ${FREETYPE_FOUND} )
endif()
```

This is what my secondary cmake script (in folder freetype-2.5.5) looks like, it will look very different in your case but at least it's an example. https://github.com/cbeck88/cegui-emscripten/blob/d24fcd6a5dc4697b8718564fadb25d76c255bce2/lib/freetype-2.5.5/CMakeLists.txt

Note especially some of these lines at the very end `SET(FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${INCL} PARENT_SCOPE)` which you might need to use if you do it this way.

Comment: The problem is that the library is trying to build first at which time I have no variables set so compilation fails. Also, the library has no notion ahead of time what the include src dir will be called.

Comment: "Also, the library has no notion ahead of time what the include src dir will be called." I don't know what that means. Does the library actually depend on the source files in your primary project? If so then it wouldn't normally be called a library. A library is something that you depend on externally, that doesn't depend back on you.

Comment: Ok I reread your question. Drew: you should just move the variable processing earlier in the cmake script, before you call add_subdirectory. Then the configuration variables will be available to the secondary script. In my example project, many of the library build scripts depend on variables set either by the user or by cmake in the primary build script.

Comment: I thought a little more about what you said regarding how the code I'm working with is organized. I'm artificially treating it as a library and that's my problem - it's not really a library. I'm going to update my question with the solution and the pitfalls of trying to cram a square peg in a round hole. Thanks for your helpful answer.